Account Abstraction on Private blockchain?
I want to know about that is it possible to implement account abstraction on private blockchain (POA) based geth client / Ganache client?

Yes.
There are various levels and ways to implement account abstraction. What is possible for your own blockchain depends on how much you are willing to change the blockchain.
If you do not want to change the consensus mechanism (which is very difficult to accomplish properly), you can do something similar to Ethereum's AA. But if you are ok with doing bigger changes, you can implement very native account abstraction - which is a lot more potent than Ethereum's "easy" version.
However, for all variants, you have to know what you're doing. None of them are easy to implement.

Thanks. I am willing to implement as simple as possible where user does not have to handle private key. Can you provide me some guide or tutorial link?

Well the user has to have some way of authorization.. Anyway, I'm really not an expert at AA. Please have a look at Ethereum mainnet has implemented it currently - it's far from trivial, but that's relatively easy implementation on top of regular EVM.
